# How should I format the data

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, formatting, react-chartjs-2

I don't understand what this want from me

> How to parse the dataset. The parsing can be disabled by specifying
> parsing: false at chart options or dataset. If parsing is disabled,
> data must be sorted and in the formats the associated chart type and
> scales use internally.

i have array like this

```
{
  "prices": [
    [
      1400025600000,
      444.2467
    ],
    [
      1400112000000,
      444.25
    ],
    [
      1400198400000,
      445.165
    ],
    [
      1400284800000,
      445.8533
    ],
    [
      1400371200000,
      444.2133
    ],
    [
      1400457600000,
      443.87
    ],
```

and more values

I am using react-chartjs2 to display data from API. I don't get the error, but when parsing is turned off, the graph lines just not draw. I need to disable parsing to use the data decimation. More information [Chartjs Decimation](https://chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/decimation.html)

Comment: What exaclty is your question? Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get started.

Comment: how should i format this array based on these conditions

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a charting library. It might help to say which one. Also, if you're getting a specific error, say what that is.

Comment: @MichaelDyck am using react-chartjs2 to display data from API. I don't get the error, but when parsing is turned off, the graph lines just not draw. I need to disable parsing to use the data decimation. More information https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/decimation.html 

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should add that info to the question, so that it isn't buried down here. Also, there's a tag [react-chartjs-2]; adding it to your question should increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a Line chart, then the data should be in this (internal) form `{ x, y }`.

Example:

```
{x: 1694265716000, y: 1.15}
```